# jQuery button enable/disable based on input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is test I created, how can I apply the button disable or enable to both inputs? As you can see the below code only works '.link_address'. I set keyup since once dom is loaded, we still need to check for weather inputs are empty or not. what am I doing wrong here? I tried foreach that checks all inputs under 'input_fields_wrap' , maybe I set it up wrong, but wasn't working either

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.confirm-btn').attr('disabled', true);

  var valid_check = $('.link_address') || $('.link_name');
  valid_check.keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length != 0) {
      $('.confirm-btn').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('.confirm-btn').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <input type="text" class="link_address">
    <input type="text" class="link_name">
  </div>

  <button class="confirm-btn">Add More Fields</button>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="./js/test.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the button to be enabled only if **both** input fields have values?

Comment: @ochi ya sorry, only when both inputs are filled

Comment: OK, updated my answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current statement is `var valid_check = $('.link_address') || $('.link_name');`.

Remember, `||` is a Javascript construct, not some kind jQuery magic. It has no special combination abilities when used with jQuery, it only means what it has always meant: a logical `OR` comparison.

So what you're saying is "*If `$('.link_address')` is a truthy value, set `valid_check` to that. If not, then set `valid_check` to `$('.link_name')`*". However, jQuery objects are always truthy, so it will never touch `$('.link_name')` with that expression.

jQuery has it's own way of combining multiple selectors in to one object, which I have demonstrated below. (Also, you want to use `prop` instead of `attr`, trust me).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.confirm-btn').attr('disabled', true);

    var valid_check = $('.link_address,.link_name');
    valid_check.keyup(function () {
        if ($('.link_address').val().length != 0 && $('.link_name').val().length != 0) {
            $('.confirm-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('.confirm-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
      <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <input type="text" class="link_address">
            <input type="text" class="link_name">
        </div>

        <button class="confirm-btn">Add More Fields</button>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="./js/test.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion I wanted the button to be enabled only when both inputs are filled

Comment: @AnuRajan I've updated my answer per those specifications. You need to check both inputs each time either of them change, which the answer now reflects.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do:

**Note**: `.input_fields_wrap :input` is probably not the best selector here, you should make sure it only captures the inputs that are relevant.

```js
// Upon page load
$(() => {
  // When user releases a key on any relevant input field
  $('.input_fields_wrap :input').on('keyup', () => {
    // Disable confirm button if at least one of them has an empty value
    $('.confirm-btn')
      .prop('disabled', $('.input_fields_wrap :input')
        .toArray()
        .some(input => $(input).val().length === 0)
      );
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <input type="text" class="link_address">
  <input type="text" class="link_name">
</div>

<button class="confirm-btn" disabled>Add More Fields</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="./js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have `var valid_check = $('.link_address') || $('.link_name');`

which means your variable (`valid_check`) will contain a handle to one, or the other.  Since the first one is always found, the OR part of it is not executed (by-passed).

The event listener is, thus, only applied to the first element (input) and never the second.

You may want to change your selector so that it applies to all the fields you want to take into account for validation. I used `$("input")` but you can be more specific if you want.

Something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // start with the button disabled
  $('.confirm-btn').attr('disabled', true);

  $(".input_fields_wrap > input").on('keyup', function() {
    // all the inputs into an array
    var inputList = $(".input_fields_wrap > input");
    // check to see if one has a value length of 0 (i.e. no input)
    var isDisabled = inputList.toArray().some(f => $(f).val().length === 0);
    
    // enable/disable button now
    $('.confirm-btn').attr('disabled', isDisabled);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <input type="text" class="link_address">
  <input type="text" class="link_name">
</div>

<button class="confirm-btn">Add More Fields</button>
```